# Rails 3: has_many :uniq issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is a sample model setup (barebone Rails 3.0.5):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_posts, through: :comments, source: :post, uniq: true
end
```

Now the following works correctly:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > user.commented_posts.count
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "posts".id) FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "posts".id = "comments".post_id WHERE (("comments".user_id = 1))
=> 1
```

But adding condition makes active record 'forget' about `uniq: true` bit:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > user.commented_posts.where("posts.id != 42").count
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "posts".id = "comments".post_id WHERE (("comments".user_id = 1)) AND (posts.id != 42)
=> 2
```

Bug? Or what am I missing?

**edit:**

`all` works:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > user.commented_posts.where("posts.id != 42").all
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "posts".id = "comments".post_id WHERE (("comments".user_id = 1)) AND (posts.id != 42)
=> [#<Post id: 1, created_at: "2011-03-07 12:17:30", updated_at: "2011-03-07 12:17:30">]
```

explicit `uniq` too:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > user.commented_posts.where("posts.id != 42").uniq.count
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "posts".id = "comments".post_id WHERE (("comments".user_id = 1)) AND (posts.id != 42)
=> 1
```

**edit 2**

Indeed bug in Rails. I submitted a patch. Please upvote it so it gets through sooner. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2924#issuecomment-3317185

Comment: Touche. You might try being more polite to people who take a moment to try to help.

Comment: It is not that you didn't know the syntax. It is that your answer made no sense, since, assuming incorrect syntax, the above example would simply never compile. Let alone misconstructing sql queries. Which means you didn't bother thinking much before answering. Luckily, SO let us discourage such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this as well on both 3.0.9 and 3.0.10. I consider it an arel bug, although there might be some reason as to why it behaves this way.

I tried overriding count on the join method...

```
has_many :commented_posts, through: :comments, source: :post, uniq: true do
  def count(column_name = nil, opts = {})
    super(column_name || 'users.id', opts.reverse_merge(distinct: true))
  end
end
```

But arel ignores the count method if a condition is present. This is why I think it's a bug.

As a hacking solution, I'm using @comments.count('users.id', distinct: true) to force arel to behave in situations where @comments might have a condition attached in the controller.

Comment: I submitted a bug (with patch) a while ago but the ticket was closed when they migrated from lighthouse to github issues. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1003

Comment: artemave, can you create a new ticket from your old one? Your fix should be incorporated into rails 3.1 IMHO.

Comment: I'll make sure it still fails on rails master (it probably does) and resubmit the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the explicit uniq is causing the count to occur from the array in memory rather than doing a count in the database. You can tell this is true from the SELECT DISTINCT rather than SELECT COUNT DISTINCT. This will pull all the entries from the DB into rails and then count them.

It is possible to get the DB to do this by passing a couple of parameters to count

collection.count(:id, :distinct => true) will cause the correct SQL code to be generated.

Comment: Explicit uniq.count indeed performs count in memory. My example was more to show that uniq is not fundamentally broken (on my setup). Perhaps that bit was misleading. Other than that, you answer doesn't even address the issue.

Comment: I thought the point of the question was that the count method does not work correctly when it follows a where method call. Which is true. My answer was meant to demonstrate a work around for the bug which still had the benefit of performing the count in the database.  I believe in this case that the uniq: true qualifier is broken, while the method call to uniq for counting the elements of a collection is not broken. These are two different things, explicitly one of them generates an incorrect SQL statement.

Comment: "Bug? Or what am I missing?" is not exactly a "How do I get it work?" type of question, is it?